# Move a 3d rigidbody to its facing direction in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the following scene:

[image]

I want the robot to move to each facing direction, so I tried:

```
rigidbody.AddForce(rigidbody.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up* speed));
```

And the robot is moving up like jumping.

I tried:

```
rigidbody.AddForce(rigidbody.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward* speed));
```

but the robot is falling down

[image]

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: What kind of collider does he have on him?

Comment: RigidBody is probably falling ahead because of the friction with the floor. Just an hint, if you access transform.forward you can simplify the code because it already contains forward vector in world space coords.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj I used a box collider on from his feet to head.

Answer (score 0):

He is most likely falling down because he is falling over due to Physics.

You can give his Rigidbody rotation constraints to freeze his rotation in X and Z axes - so he can still turn to face a direction, but he cannot fall over. The use your "forward" code to move him.

These constraints can also be accessed from code, so you can for example turn them off if he is killed, so he falls over:

```
rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
```

Comment: I think I managed to make it work freezing the x and the z rotation. I will test it a bit more.